# How to create unordered list with row columns

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Basically I'd like to extend this [demo](http://www.prodevtips.com/demos/drag_drop_tree/) and turn text nodes into rows with multiple columns and equal (fixed) width. Sort of a classic table with indented rows.
The tree (unordered list) looks like this at the moment:

[image]

and I'd like to add some additional columns:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get more responses and of a better quality if you explain your requirements better. Expecting people to follow a link to find out what you are trying it to achieve is a little elf conceited to be honest. After all, people are offering their time and knowledge to you for free ad out of kindness. The least you can do is make it as easy as possible to help gou. By all means refer to the link, but only as an additional point of reference.

Just saying.....